# ¿Cómo ajustar un elemento button con css?

Tags: css, html5

Tengo un `button` el cuál lo quiero mover más hacía abajo, la cuestión es que como está dentro de un `div` que contiene un titulo, entonces lo mueve, lo que quiero es que el titulo se mantenga así como está y `button` quede abajo, lo logré haciéndolo con `position: absolute` y moviendolo con las propiedades `bottom` y `right`, pero pues, obviamente no se ajusta con el `div` ni la pantalla, entonces, lo quité así qué si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradezco.

Dejo una imagen de como se ve y dónde está marcado es más o menos donde quiero que esté

[image: vista previa]

Y aquí el código `html` de como está actualmente

```
<header>
        <div class="container text-center card rounded shadow">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="../images/JOMAR-LOGO.png" class="rounded card-img" width="300" alt="jomar-logo">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 center-content">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h1 class="text-center font-weight-bold">Inducción de nuevos empleados</h1>
                        <div class="justify-content-end row">
                            <button type="button" style="" onclick="cambiarEmpleado()" class="btn btn-link">Cambiar empleado</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues iba bien encaminado a la respuesta con las propiedades que usé, mi error fue no haber quitado la clases por lo que pues quedaba totalmente desordenado, ya al quitarlos se acopló al padre y ya quedó de esta manera

```
<div class="card-body">
                        <h1 class="text-center font-weight-bold">Inducción de nuevos empleados</h1>
                        <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right:20px">
                            <button type="button" style="" onclick="cambiarEmpleado()" class="btn btn-link">Cambiar empleado</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```